# Json sending multiple results

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I send data in json format for counting visits. Problem is when i use back arrow in browser - results are send second, third ... and more times and there is one  **em** tag for every click in back arrow on browser. What i can do to overwrite results but not sending second in new place.

My controller:

```
visits_count = current_user.visits.where(:read => false).count.to_i

respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => visits_count }
```

And my js:

```
function unread(){
  $('#visits p').each( function() {
$.ajax({
  url: '/visits/unread_count',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    if (data > 0) {
      $('#visits p').append('<em>' + data +'</em>');
    }
  }
});
  });
};
```

and my view:

```
<%= link_to 'visits', visits_path, :id => "visits" %><p></p></li>
```

Comment: Don't append the data but overwrite the contents .html() function I think.

Comment: $('#visits p').html(data);

Comment: ok it works - i have right now always empty element but i think i can hide it if data <= 0